# Loop over CSV rows in jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm encountering some issues with loading data from a csv file with jekyll.
I've made some custom collections using the following `_config.yml` seup:

```
collections_dir: collections

collections:
  people:
    output: true
  publications:
    output: true
```

Now I this is what my structure looks like (just showing the relevant parts):

```
.
├── collections
│   ├── _people
│   │   ├── x.md
│   │   ├── y.md
│   └── _publications
│       └── data.csv
├── index.html
└── _config.yml
```

When I try to loop over my collections using [this link](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/06-data-files/) as a guide it doesn't seem to work

```
# except from my index.html file
{% for row in site.publications.data %}
    <p>name: {{row.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after a data file, rather than a collection here. The main differences are:

- Data files can have each item as entries in a single file, or separate files in a subfolder of `_data`
- Collections have each item as a separate file only
- Data entries do not output a page per entry
- Collections can output a page per entry

Here's how you would change this to data:

1. Move `collections/publications/data.csv` to `_data/publications.csv`
2. Remove the `publications` entry from `collections` in `_config.yml`
3. Change your loop to the following:

   ```
   {% for row in site.data.publications %}
     <p>name: {{ row.name }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

If you want to use a **data file and output a page per entry**, a popular plugin to do so is https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen

Alternatively, you could split the CSV into separate Markdown files and use a collection to avoid adding a plugin.